# R files download issues from URLs

Tags: r, web-scraping, xpath, rvest, httr

I have a list of URLs in the format: https://erc.undp.org/evaluation/evaluations/detail/7834

and need to download the .pdf and .docx files. One needs to click on these to download the files. The hyperlink is also not visible on the webpage. I have tried to get the xpath but it doesn't return the variable. I have also tried various other ways including :

```
library(rvest)
# Get the HTML of the webpage
html <- read_html("https://erc.undp.org/evaluation/evaluations/detail/7834? 
        tab=documents")
# Find all the links on the webpage that point to downloadable documents
links <- html %>%
html_nodes("a") %>%
html_attr("href")
```

Is there any way to get the list of URLs for the documents available on the above page. I could use the download.files() to download once I have the list of URLs.

Comment: {rvest} is insufficient for this because it can't run JavaScript; you'd need something like {splashr} or {RSelenium} that runs a headless browser. There may be better options now; it's been a while since I've bothered—it can be a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pages like this you can often find the data within one of the javascript sections of the page, but you can't access it using the usual `rvest` methods. However, if you convert the whole page to text, you can then use (for example) `stringr` functions to isolate the parts you need.

You will need to use something like Chrome's `inspect` function to work out what is going on, and it can be hard to find. Also, try to do one manually in a browser and note how the URLs are formed.

In this case, if you inspect the page in chrome and search the "sources", you can find a `documentId` buried in the javascript. Following through manually on a browser, there is a simple download page for each document based on this `documentId`. This works for me...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
    
links <- read_html("https://erc.undp.org/evaluation/evaluations/detail/7834?tab=documents") %>% 
  as.character() %>% #save whole page as character
  str_extract_all("\\{.+\\}") %>% #data is in { }
  pluck(1) %>% #unlist
  tail(1) %>%  #we want the last element
  str_extract_all("documentId.+?\\,") %>% #look for documentIds
  pluck(1) %>% #unlist
  str_extract("\\d+") %>% #extract numeric Id
  paste0("https://erc.undp.org/evaluation/documents/download/", .) #create URL

links
[1] "https://erc.undp.org/evaluation/documents/download/18959"
[2] "https://erc.undp.org/evaluation/documents/download/18971"
```

You can then pass these to `download.file` or whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: I was able to generate the list of URLs using your code and download them using download.file()